# Python - Is it possible to refer to multiple different variables using different variable?

Tags: python

Sorry if the title is confusing but I couldn't think of a better way to word it.
I'm making a game with a friendship system and this is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
playerChar = "Adam";
opinion_[playerChar]_Betty = 20;
```

so that later I can check

```
if opinion_Adam_Betty == 20;
```

`playerChar` could be set to `Adam`, `Betty`, or `Carmen`.

So if `playerChar` was set to `Adam`, then `opinion_[playerChar]_Betty` and `opinion_Adam_Betty` would actually refer to the same variable, but if `playerChar` was set to `Carmen`, `opinion_[playerChar]_Betty` would be referring to the variable `opinion_Carmen_Betty` instead, and no longer be the same variable as `opinion_Adam_Betty`.

In essence, I want `opinion_[playerChar]_Betty` to be able to refer to different variables depending on what the variable `playerChar` is set to. Not sure if this is possible or not (or if I'm just overcomplicating things) but it would make some things super convenient for me if it were.

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: Are you trying to associated a value between two players?

Comment: Is opinion.Adam.Betty == opinion.Betty.Adam ?

Comment: The short answer: no, you cannot create a variable name from another variable's value. Instead you should use an appropriate data structure, most likely a dictionary or maybe a class. See the answers to the questions linked at the top of this page for further suggestions and discussion.

Comment: No, opinion.Adam.Betty would have a separate value from opinion.Betty.Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use nested dictionaries.  Using `defaultdict` specifically saves you a bunch of init work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

opinion = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

playerChar = "Adam"
opinion[playerChar]["Betty"] = 20

if opinion["Adam"]["Betty"] == 20:
    print("Adam likes Betty <3")

if opinion["Betty"]["Adam"] < 20:
    print("it's not mutual tho </3")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!!
I'm still really new to Python and I had no idea dictionaries could be used in that way